# Confused about Facebook review process

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to develop an iOS app which can pull your Facebook videos. Very similar to [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xcs.fbvideos) the Android app except the video download part. For this I need `user_videos` permission and for that my app should go through the app review process. Now they are asking for `App Video` and `App runtime`. I can give them but that has nothing but fb login screens with no videos. How should I proceed with this app?

EDIT:
I created a dummy app and submitted the runtime for it. [Video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5feet7109yriya/Video%20App%20Review.mp4?dl=0)

Now as I dont have the `user_video` permission, I can only show placeholder videos (as shown in video). I explained my situation to them, and their reply was:

`"Developers can configure a test user that has granted tokens for the requested permission. Please submit your app after you have incorporated the requested permission."`

A test user is not allowed to get tagged or upload a video. And graph API also gives error in case I try to do that. How a test user can solve my problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook people are sometimes anxious to know if your app is not using any content that will violate facebook content policy. Just make a simple video of your two screens and they will approve the app in a short period.

**Update**

Following are the steps on facebook developer dashboard which will show you how to upload the video for review of your app.

Status and review -> Click on add notes in App detail section -> Enter the steps to be reproduced by facebook review team -> upload a screencast (Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/examples#screencast )

[image: Status and review]
[image: Steps to be reproduced by facebook review team]

Comment: Do you experienced it

Comment: Yup, one of my colleague faced the same issue and got approval of his app in around 5 to 6 days.

Comment: Delay might be expected due to christmas break.

Comment: @RohitPradhan Please check the update in answer and let me know if you need any other help.